# Ogre undefined reference to boost, Fuerte onFedora 18

Tags: boost, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having issues building gazebo and ogre for a fuerte install on Fedora 18. The issue is it isn't recognizing the boost library for some reason. It is installed and up to date but I get the following error.

```
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/OgreXMLConverter.dir/src/tinyxml.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/OgreXMLConverter.dir/src/tinyxmlerror.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/OgreXMLConverter.dir/src/tinyxmlparser.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const*)'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::get_id()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join()'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
../../lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.3: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::disable_interruption()'
```

I've been trying to make this go away by adding -lboost_system manually to the LFLAGs section of the Makefile but that doesn't help. The libboost.so family is in /usr/libs and /usr/include/boost has all the hpp files. What can I do to get ogre to correctly find the libraries?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65695/ogre-undefined-reference-to-boost,-fuerte--onfedora-18/) by [flashedarling](https://answers.ros.org/users/5110/flashedarling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-06-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that your current Boost version has those symbols. I don't remember what commands are used to see the list of exported functions in Linux. On Mac it's `otool -TV <library>` or `nm <library>`.
There could be a Boost version mismatch and some functions are missing. I successfully compiled Ogre with boos149. I gave up on trying building gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0